# why do we lose rep when we downvote answers

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes

The title just it, I really don't know if someone else has posted the same thing, but just keen to know, ***I mean if we feel an answer is no good, shouldn't we be given the freedom to down vote it at no cost***?

Comment: BTW, welcome to meta.Chem, and don't take the possible future downvotes seriously. On meta, votes indicate everything from disagreement to lack of research, and usually don't reflect post quality. Good luck :)

Comment: Please see: [Why do you lose reputation for down-voting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15863/why-do-you-lose-reputation-for-down-voting) on [meta.SE]

Comment: Thanks for those fast responses, and @M.A.R., all cool with it. Dont really mind getting taken for a ride in the beginning, ( as a wise man once said, anything that doesn't kill you, only makes you stronger )

Comment: @Supernova In a sideways sort of manner it's also encouragement to contribute positively: Upset about that point you lost when casting a downvote? Better go post a good question or answer (or suggest some good edits) to recover! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's this Supernova user. I really don't like their avatar and I want to downvote everything they say. I don't care that's not a valid reason for voting and votes should only be on the content, not the user. The votes are all anonymous, so I should be fine, right?

Oh shucks. I lose 1 WHOLE rep for downvoting answers?! Oh no, I guess the downvoting spree of Supernova is cancelled. :(

Comment: ohk, so its more like a preventive mech, to agaisnt downvoting sprees. (P.S: since newbies like me are down on rep, every drop counts.imho) @M.A.R.

Comment: @Supernova there used to be the same penalty for questions, but it eventually was removed because questions have a much bigger potential to be crappy. (Also 1 rep removal is less than 1 % of your total rep, it's just exaggerated because you consider it a loss, not investment in helping the quality of your site)

Comment: BTW, if you downvote an answer and it's subsequently deleted, you regain the 1 rep you lost by downvoting it.

Comment: oh, so technically, were free to downvote what doesn't seem proper, at no cost @M.A.R., thanks again

Comment: @Supernova Fwiw *I* like your avatar.

Comment: thanks dude @JasonC